# Java - Mergesort isn't choosing pivot correctly

Tags: java

Just practicing some sorting algorithms. I tried to implement a recursive merge sort, but there seems to be a problem with getting a new pivot for each recursive call.

I feel like my code should be working... but I'm new to using ArrayList as a data structure... and only have experience with arrays. I needed a dynamic-sized array, so I'm using an ArrayList.

It just keeps spitting out pivot = 1 until it overflows:

```
pivot: 1
pivot: 1
pivot: 1
pivot: 1
pivot: 1
...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

**code:**

```
      import java.util.*;

public class Sorts{
    static Sorts run;               
    List<Integer> initialList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public Sorts() {

        //List<Integer> initialList = new ArrayList<Integer>();


        initialList.add(1);
        initialList.add(4);
        initialList.add(8);
        initialList.add(2);
        initialList.add(3);
        initialList.add(7);
        initialList.add(9);


        System.out.print("List of values: (");
        for (int value: initialList) {
            System.out.print(value);
        }
        System.out.println(")");

        //output sorted array
        System.out.println("Sorted list: " + mergeSort(initialList));                                                          
    }

    public List<Integer> mergeSort(List<Integer> list) {                               
        if (list.size() <= 1) {
            return list;
        }

        //after each recursion, generate two new sub lists
        List<Integer> left = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<Integer> right = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 

        //generate new pivot for each new list
        int middle = list.size()/2;
        System.out.println("middle: " + middle);

        int i = 0;
        for (int x: list) {
            if (i < middle) {
                left.add(x);
            }
            else {
                right.add(x);
            }
            i++;
        }

        //call mergeSort, passing in each new sublist (left, right)
      left = mergeSort(left);
      right = mergeSort(right);

       return mergeLists(left, right);
     }

    public List<Integer> mergeLists (List<Integer> left, List<Integer> right) {
        List<Integer> sortedList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int i = 0;
        while (left.size() > 0 || right.size() > 0) {
            if (left.size() > 0 && right.size() > 0) {
                if (left.get(i) <= right.get(i)) {
                    sortedList.add(left.get(i));
                }
                else {
                    sortedList.add(right.get(i));
                }
            }
            else if (left.size() > 0) {
                sortedList.add(left.get(i));
            }
            else if (right.size() > 0) {
                sortedList.add(right.get(i));
            }
        }

        for (int value : sortedList) {
            System.out.println(value);
        }
        return sortedList;
    }

    public static void main(String []args){
        run = new Sorts();
    }
}
```

Any thoughts? Am I using the ArrayList incorrectly?

Thanks!

Comment: Declare the List<Integer> initialList; out side the constructor

Comment: @codeMan that did not fix it

Comment: Why do you compare list elements with index? Doesn't make sense, does it?

Comment: @DenisTulskiy True... I'm just getting the hang of shorthand for loops, so I messed that up. I changed the looping to loop through the index, and then add the element per Luiggi Mendoza's answer.

Comment: And it worked? P.S. Deleted my answer since I realized I was thinking of quicksort.

Comment: If you keep updating the code with your current (and still wrong) solution our answers lose any value for future readers. If you want to add the current code, please separate it from the initial problem(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're splitting the list in the wrong way:

```
for (int i: initialList) {
    if (i < pivot) {
        left.add(i);
    }
    else {
        right.add(i);
    }
}
```

`i` is the element in `initialList`, not the index of the element. Change this to:

```
int i = 0;
for (int x: initialList) {
    if (i < pivot) {
        left.add(x);
    }
    else {
        right.add(x);
    }
    i++;
}
```

For any downvoter: I've tested this and worked :).

Also, there's a problem in your `merge` algorithm. You should merge both lists while sorting the elements but you're just inserting the values of left and then the values of right (but maybe could be for test purposes).

---

Based on your edit, now you have a new problem when getting the pivot:

```
int pivot = list.get(list.size()/2);
```

This should be as you posted in original code:

```
int pivot = initialList.size()/2;
```

Note that people might be telling you some odd advices since `pivot` is used in [QuickSort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) and you just use `middle` or `mid` in [MergeSort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mergesort)

Comment: this doesn't seem to fix the issue. It now infinitely loops through outputting pivot as 4

Comment: @Growler Strange, I just copy/pasted your current code and changed the code below pivot like shown here and it worked (it returned the same list though). Maybe you're making something else that's outside the posted code.

Comment: my full code has been added above as you have done. It only keeps spitting out `pivot: 4`

Comment: @Growler I recommend you to create a new class, copy/paste the code posted in your question and replace the code I'm pointing out, then run it. By the way, I just used `new Sorts()` and ran like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort

You don't need to compare with pivot, it is not a partition sort you're implementing. Just split the list in two, something like this.

```
left = list.sublist(0, pivot);
right = list.sublist(pivot, list.length())
```

Comment: `var integer middle = length(m) / 2...
    for each x in m before middle
         add x to left...
    for each x in m after or equal middle
         add x to right...` Did I read this incorrectly? Aren't they comparing it against the pivot element?

Comment: @Growler: this phrasing is assuming you're using linked lists (or tapes) and you need to go through the list to split it. Translating to human, it's more like: `for each x in m whose index is less than middle... etc`

Comment: If I do what you recommended, `left = list.sublist(0, pivot);`, where would the recursive call be (like, `left = mergeSort(left);`)

Comment: @Growler: same place as it is now

Comment: okay, I've updated my code above. I'm getting IndexOutOfBound Exceptions

Comment: @Growler: this time pivot should be middle index, not middle element. and your mergeList method is still completely wrong. See Luiggi Mendoza's answer.