# mergeSort with List interface

Tags: java, sorting

I wrote the following code, but I'm getting a stack overflow. The merge method works ok when tested on its own. When I look at the code now I have tunnel vision and I cant understand why it doesn't work, so could someone point the error out to me. Thank a lot!

```
public static List<Comparable> mergeSort(List <Comparable> target){
    if(target.size() <  2)
        return target;

    return merge(mergeSort(copy(0,(target.size()-1)/2 + 1,target)),mergeSort(copy((target.size()-1)/2 + 1,target.size(),target)));
}

private static List<Comparable> merge(List<Comparable> target1,List<Comparable> target2){
    List <Comparable> result = new ArrayList <Comparable>();

    while(target1.size() > 0 || target2.size() > 0){
        if(target1.isEmpty()) 
            result.add(target2.remove(0));
        else if(target2.isEmpty()) 
            result.add(target1.remove(0));
        else if(target1.get(0).compareTo(target2.get(0)) < 0)
            result.add(target1.remove(0));
        else    
            result.add(target2.remove(0));
    }

   return result;
}

private static List<Comparable> copy(int startIndex, int endIndex, List<Comparable> target){
    List <Comparable> result = new ArrayList <Comparable>();

    for(int i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++)
       result.add(target.get(i)); 

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Adding a stacktrace will help..

Comment: @vidit: There is only one point of recursion. What do you expect to see in the stack trace except that line?

Comment: I would honestly recommend debugging your code. Most `StackOverflowExceptions` can be really quickly sussed out by just looking at each value on each recursive call, and work out which is the value that isn't changing in the way it should be.

Comment: @JanusTroelsen- You are right, I'm noob.

Comment: I've just tested out this code, with my own class that implements `comparable` and it works fine. What test data are you using?

Comment: Just a List of Comparable references that point to Integer Objects with randomly assigned values between 0 and 1000, I implemented a insertionSort and selectionSort with the same data and they work fine? Thanks for testing my code btw¨

Comment: @John I cannot replicate the exception either. Just tried with a 1000 integers with random values. It works. Have tried various other things also and it works every time.

Comment: Wow, WTF!! I ran my code 6 times and stack overflow each time, then after the 7th time it was gone? ****** netbeans.

Comment: Related: [http://stackoverflow.com/q/15579425/1065197](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15579425/1065197). I provide a merge sort implementation using `List` interface and `Iterator` (instead of `get` and `remove` methods that are time costly on `LinkedList` implementations of `List`). The only difference will be comparing the elements using `>` or `<` with `compareTo` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your implementation of mergeSort doesn't scale very well. You are using your `copy` method to copy the appropriate range of the input list as input for a recursive call to `mergeSort`. If you consider the whole depth of the recursion, you need additional space the size of the entire input list on each level.

This means your code needs memory of log2(n) times n where n is the size of your input list. If you are about to mergeSort a list of size 65'536 elements, your code will create copies of it such that it will use a peak amount of log2(65'536) = 16 times the memory requirements of your input table. This might very well lead to a `StackOverflowException`.

To remedy this, I'd rewrite the `mergeSort` method (or rather create an overloaded version of it) to accept a list together with lower and upper bounds pointing into the list. That way, you won't need to copy the list on each recursion step. On the other hand, as soon as the range delimited by the lower and upper bounds contains just one element, you return a new `List` containing just this single element which `merge()` will operate on. That way, you only copy the whole input list once (i.e. at the lowest recursion level), and you'll end up using only twice the memory that the input list occupies (in complexity terms, `O(n)`). As soon as `merge()` will have passed over these single-element-lists and will have created a new intermediate result list, the single-element-lists will be available for GC.

Comment: Thanks that implementation is very cool and I will implement it in my code, but right now Im randomly getting a stack overflow with data that contains only 10 objects. Sometimes it will not have a stack overflow and run, but when it does the objects are not sorted, so there must be a logic error. Im confused because people said it worked for them, did it just run with out errors for them or did it actually sort the data for them? Thanks!

Comment: Hm, you're having stack overflows with only 10 objects? That's really odd, the only cause for this I can imagine would be some accidental infinite loop happening in the code. But your divide step and choosing of indexes looks reasonable, and also the while loop in the merge step seems to be certain to terminate... Are you sure this code is the cause for the stack overflow and not something around it?

Comment: k, please forget what I just said. The stack overflow is being caused by the subsequent binary search, which makes sense because it expects a sorted list and if the merge sort is not working properly the binary wont either. So I guess the only problem I have now is that the algorithm isn't actually working, it has some kind of logic error.

Comment: Try to output/log the sorted array to check if it is sorted in the correct order. Does your binary search handle duplicate values, which can occur due to random values, correctly?