# Difference between a for-loop and a while-loop using an Iterator

Tags: java, performance, loops, iterator

Iterator using while-loop:

```
List<DataType> list = new ArrayList<DataType>();  
Iterator<YourDataType> it = yourList.iterator();  
while (it.hasNext())   
   // Do something
```

Iterator using for-loop:

```
   List<DataType> list = new ArrayList<DataType>();
   for ( Iterator<DataType> it = list.iterator(); list.hasNext(); ) 
      // Do something
```

I've read that the for-loop minimizes the scope of the Iterator to the loop itself. What exactly does that mean? Should I use the for-loop insteed of the while-loop?

Comment: W.r.t. minimizing scope, it's (in my head, at least) like using a local variable over a global variable. Can anyone whether this is comparable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is basically

### In for loop:

```
for (Iterator<DataType> it = list.iterator(); list.hasNext(); )
```

In this case, you are declaring the Iterator object locally and it will be `eligible for GC(garbage collection) after the for loop`.

### **In while loop**,

`while (it.hasNext())` since you have declared the object Iterator outside a loop. So its **scope is may be** `the entire program` or the `method it is in`.
Or incase if it is referenced anywhere, so it **wont be eligible for GC**.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

> the for-loop minimizes the scope of the Iterator to the loop itself. What exactly does that mean?

To use the `Iterator` on the `while` loop, you must declare and initialize it **before** being using in the `while` loop. So, you can do this:

```
List<DataType> list = new ArrayList<DataType>();  
Iterator<YourDataType> it = yourList.iterator();  
while (it.hasNext()) {
}
it.hasNext(); //this compiles and will return false
```

In the `for` loop, the `Iterator` is declared to be inside the scope of the `for` loop, so it can be used only inside the body of this loop.

```
List<DataType> list = new ArrayList<DataType>();
for ( Iterator<DataType> it = list.iterator(); list.hasNext(); ) {
}
it.hasNext(); //this won't work and is a compiler error since the variable it's outside its scope
```

> Should I use the for-loop insteed of the while-loop?

This entirely depends on your needs. Usually, if you're going to consume all the elements of the iterator in a single loop, it is better to use the `for` loop approach, and it will be better using the enhanced `for` loop that already uses `Iterator` behind the scenes:

```
for(DataType data : list) {
    //...
}
```

In cases where you won't navigate through all the elements of the iterator in the loop, it would be better to use a `while`. An example of this could be [implementing a merge sort](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15579968/1065197) (Note: this example is entirely for learning purposes).

Answer (score 1):

Because you declare the iterator inside the for loop, you won't be able to use it outside of it. Its scope will be limited to the for-loop block.

Use what makes more sense in your case. Do you need the iterator after you've iterated over all the elements in your collection? Use the while-loop. If you don't care for it, use the for-loop.

Note that when things go out of scope, they become eligible for garbage collection.

Answer (score 1):

There are two important differences in syntax and maintenance.

**Syntax**

The scope of the variable is different. In the `for` case, the variable is only accessible within the for header and body, while in the `while` case it is available after the loop. As a general rule, it's better to have tighter scopes, less variables in-flight mean less context to worry about when coding.

**Maintenance**

The `for loop` has the neat advantage of grouping all the iterations operations close together, so they can be inspected in one shot and so checked.

Apart from this:

`for` loops are more readable and all-around better for regular iteration patterns where as `while` loops should be reserved to irregular iteration patterns

Comment: I don't understand the Maintenance part..doesn't it depend on the programmers' opinion ?

Comment: Maintenance in the sense that if we have to change or update the iteration operation ie the logic or the step, we can find everything at a single place

Answer (score 1):

As JNL said, with a limited scope the garbage-collection can collect it directly after the loop instead of until the next `}`.

Normally this is of small concern - an iterator doesn't really take up much memory and the scope normally ends pretty quickly after the iterator is used. For instance, if you put both your code samples in a method, they will yield the same scope. Another way to limit the scope of the while loop is to add curly brackets around it, as such:

```
{
   List<DataType> list = new ArrayList<DataType>();  
   Iterator<YourDataType> it = yourList.iterator();  
   while (it.hasNext())   
      // Do something
}
```

This will also limit the scope of `list`, which is more heavy in memory usage than the iterator and thus more relevant.

---

TL;DR

Doesn't matter.